# How to achieve infinite scrolling in jsp using servlet,jsp and ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, jdbc, infinite-scroll

Please help, I am really stuck with my project here, all I am getting is additional plugins which you have to buy.
I don't want to buy anything, please advise how can I achieve this , I am using mysql as my Db and JDBC to connect.
I want to list all employees with their photos but 10 at a time and further when we scroll down.

Comment: What have you tried? https://www.google.de/search?q=jsp%20ajax%20infinite%20scroll%20tutorial

Comment: You may find interesting information here http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/